# Escribir un archivo .JSON con JS/JQUERY/AJAX y NODE JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, nodejs, json

queria saber si es posible realizar esto...tengo que llevar a cabo un simulador el cual debe guardar datos de clientes, pero de manera local, digamos abrir el html en un navegador(local server), y al llenar el form enviar los datos al JSONFILE, para hacer llamadas ajax tanto de get como de post.
He visto que node, puede escribir en archivos, con la funcion require(fs), pero no se si puede hacerlo sin un servidor...Soy nuevo en esto y estoy bastante perdido.
Gracias

Comment: Varias cosas, primero, el proyecto tu carpeta node_modules es donde se encuentran las librerías en cualquier proyecto que use Node o npm como tal, lo otro es que recuerda que Node es el server http, que se programa con JavaScript, En este caso concreto podrías usar Express es un framework de Node, que te hara la vida muchísimo mas fácil. Recuerda el HTML es el lenguaje de marcado para lo que vera el usuario, y el JavaScript que interviene con el HTML no es Node, el JS que interviene en este caso es el. En tu caso no pasas la carpeta node_modules, en el archivo package.json esta todo así que co

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correr Node en local es correr un servidor, perfectamente Node puede escribir su archivo en el lugar donde determine claro si formulario debería apuntar a su node y pasar los parámetros que usted decida que pasara y como los obtiene en Node. luego escribe o determina lo que hará en su node server local, el server de node puede estar en el localhost y sigue siendo un servidor por el hecho de que sirve información en el protocolo http.

Comment: Excelente nelson, era una duda que yo tenia, por ejemplo, esto es un proyecto estudiantil, por lo cual te consulto, debo instalar NODE JS en mi proyecto, instalando los node_modules en el mismo,y si necesito entregarlo deberia solicitarle a esa persona para probarlo que ejecute node js en su pc, verdad?//Debo ejecutar node asociandolo a mi html? o html no permite asociar estos archivos, que se que son de extension JS pero no necesarmiante podrian ser interpretados por el navegador...